Does the DotNet Source Stepping feature of Visual Studio works when debugging on Linux (WSL)
I'm able to see the source code by pressing F11 when debuging on Windows, but in case of WSL just step over occurs if I press F11.
In the Options->Debugging->Symbols the checkbox Microsoft Symbol Servers is checked.
Options->Debugging->General->Enable Just My Code unchecked.
I use VS2022.

What is the detailed version of VS2022 you are using? Do you have function lock key -- 'F Lock' key on keyboard?

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.8.0
Yes, I have, but I'm sure that I press F11 correctly.

If you try to use the system's built-in keyboard: On-Screen Keyboard, will the issue persists?

No, this feature is not awailable for debugging on WSL
